# com.mysql.jdbc.driver class not found exception

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, database

I took help from [this](http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/) blog post:

But I get com.mysql.jdbc.driver class not found exception. What's different in that blog post was that they've tried to connect to mysql instead of MS SQL in my case. Here's my code so far:
package com.example.dbtry;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected TextView tv;

private static final String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://Server.com:1433/DB_name";
private static final String user = "username";
private static final String pass = "password";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testDB();
}

public void testDB() {
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            /* System.out.println("Database connection success"); */

            String result = "Database connection success\n";
          tv.setText(result);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from this_table");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next()) {
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
            }
            tv.setText(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText(e.toString());
        }   

    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I have also added permission to the Internet in the manifest.

Comment: Search for classnotfoundexception jdbc driver on SO, you'll find so many answers. The Driver class is not on your classpath. Check your jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the jar from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc430jar.htm
then change these lines as below:

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://Server.com:1433/DB_name";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: it says port 1433/DB_name is not valid. What to do with that?

Comment: according to the sample code you re trying to reach the database over port 1433 but, firstly you must open this port from firewall configuration(this link can be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx).

Comment: by the way your db must be connected with port 1433. your db has not any connection so you dont need to write port number in the url.

Answer (score 2):

Download the [`JTDS`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver from here and include it in your `classpath`. Build and run your code. It'll work.

Comment: I have used jtds driver and have included it in the classpath :S

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Mysql Connection JAR on your classpath.

This jar contains the driver: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

However as you are using MSSQL and not MySQL I suggest you find a suitable driver for MSSQL instead.

Comment: Jtds is suitable for MSSQL too :s as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with the url stated.

try running on the local host first and then give the correct url that you have. "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName"

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the class for MYSQL DB connection, you should load the class for MS SQL and should include the required jar files in the build path.
Edit the Class.forName line as below:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
```