# Connecting android app to sql server using jtds

Tags: java, android, jtds

I'm tired of searching with no result i don't know where the problem come from , i'm trying to connect my android app with the local SQl server 2008,  now i get unable to get information from sql server. please help this is my code :

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/lear_db;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
TextView coucou = new TextView(this);

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection connexion =               
        DriverManager.getConnection(url,"kamal","kamal1234"); 

        coucou.setText("Connection successful");

    } catch ( SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        coucou.setText("error1" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        coucou.setText("error2" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        coucou.setText("error0" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    setContentView(coucou);
```

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273775/2024761) to see if the `JAR` is there or not. If it still persists, then paste the error stack trace- fully.

Answer (score 1):

This is the connexion string that worked for me :

"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ adresseip +":1433/lear_db;user=youruser;password=yourpass"

than i got an other error wich is :  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

the solution is to use AsyncTask  this is a tutorial :  http://droidapp.co.uk/2011/05/12/android-dev-pre-loading-with-asynctask/

now i'm having a new error ( This errors never ends ) :

```
Unknow server host name 'unable to resolve host
```

Than it worked , on wifi with ip adresse of the host .

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use jdbc:sqlserver in this fasion

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/lear_db;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
```

or alternatively if using jtds, try:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds://10.0.2.2:1433/lear_db;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
```

Comment: For the first 1 :   i get no suitable driver and for the second i get that the syntax of the connexion url is invalid

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver is a microsoft driver, I would hope it works with Android, try it out http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774